# Jquery Closest - How does it work

Tags: jquery, closest

I have searched and referred to the earlier questions asked but may be I am too stupid to understand the issue :) .

I was referring to the jQuery implementation for **closest** and after reading it I tried to implement it on a very simple dummy example. But somehow I am not able to get the values. Below is the code I am using

```
<div> 
 <div class="firstChild">1234</div>
 <div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="firstChild">1234</div>
    <div class="secondChild">Hello</div>
    <div class="thridChild">Bye</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery code I am using it

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var value = $( ".parentDiv" ).closest( ".firstChild" ).text();
  alert(value);
});
```

but all I am getting as the value is blank. 
when I tried using

```
 var value = $( ".parentDiv" ).closest( "div" ).text();
```

I get the value from all the three child div's ie (1234 Hello Bye) as alert

How do I use closest selector to get the value of firstChild`

Comment: Read the docs. .closest() traverses up the DOM looking at ancestor elements. According to your code, .parentDiv has no ancestors, other than the body. You probably want .prev().

Comment: var value  = $( ".parentDiv" ).closest( "div" ).find('.firstChild').text();

Comment: Please see the edit. I have added a parent to .parentDiv but still it gives me blank

Comment: Not sure why is this downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Use either `.prev()` or .`parents()`:

```js
var value = $(".parentDiv").parents("div").children(".firstChild").text();
console.log(value);

var value = $(".parentDiv").prev(".firstChild").text();
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="firstChild">12345</div>
  <div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="firstChild">1234</div>
    <div class="secondChild">Hello</div>
    <div class="thridChild">Bye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with using `.closest()` in your example is that unlike `.parents()`, `.closest()` will test itself, and then go up the DOM. So `.closest('div')` will select the parentDiv div which isn't what you want. You could always use .closest() and specify a div with no class, but there's no point when two other selectors are more appropriate.